# web.config configuration Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, vcf-vcard

Everything should be good, but my web.config gives me this strange error.

How can I get this error if I am sure my stringlist in the web.config is good?

**Error:** 
    Configuration Error 
    Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

```
Parser Error Message: Unrecognized configuration section stringlist.

Source Error: 


Line 6:     <connectionStrings/>
Line 7:     
Line 8:         <stringlist key="SmtpServers">
Line 9:             <stringlistItem value="smtp.transip.nl" />
Line 10:            <stringlistItem value="localhost" />


Source File: C:\local\vCardGenerator.Website\vCardGenerator.Website\web.config    Line: 8
```

**Web.config:**

```
    <stringlist key="SmtpServers">
        <stringlistItem value="smtp.transip.nl" />
        <stringlistItem value="localhost" />
    </stringlist>
```

**Class:**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Configuration;
using Compulutions.Net;
using Compulutions.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Mail;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.Services.Description;

// System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer
// using System.Web.Mail.SmtpClient;

namespace vCardGenerator.Website.Masterpage
{
    public class SendvCard
    { //
        public void MailvCard(string recipient, string filename)
        {
        Mailer smtp = new Mailer("smtpServers");

        /* SMTP - port 25 */

        smtp.AddAttachment(filename); //.vcf file Path
        smtp.FromAddress = new MailAddress("someone@domain.nl");
        smtp.Subject = "vCard";
        smtp.MailBody = "There is a vCard waiting for you in the attachment!";
        smtp.AddRecipient(recipient);

#if !DEBUG
        try
        {
#endif
            smtp.SendMail();
#if !DEBUG
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Exception Occured:   " + ex);
                //Responds.Write("Sending vCard Failed, Please try again!")
        }
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

Similar Questions don't fit my description.
I have created an instance of SendvCard.cs and invoked the send method in the class (MailvCard)

**aspx.cs itself:**

```
        //  Calls the method at the class
            smtp.MailvCard("user@domain.com", "C:\\local\\vCardGenerator.Website" + "\\" + "FirstName_LastName" + ".vcf");
        }
```

Willing to provide any other/more information if needed.

Sincerely

Comment: What is `stringlist` and `stringlistitem`? Did you create/register these as valid config sections?

Comment: Did you forget to add stringlist to the configSections node?

Comment: Yes I did, I registered these as valid config sections.

Comment: @Rafael Show us the code where you registered it as a valid config section, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing the error because you've created a new Section (stringlist) without having declared it.  You must first declare a section in the configSections area of your web.config like so:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="stringlist" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler,System"/>
</configSections>
```

Put your stringlist below in the root of configuration:

```
  <stringlist key="SmtpServers">
    <stringlistItem value="smtp.transip.nl" />
    <stringlistItem value="localhost" />
  </stringlist>
```

See this link for examples as well as how to access these values: [Customizing SectionGroups and Sections in Web.config](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7266/Customizing-SectionGroups-and-Sections-in-Web-conf)

Also, keep in mind there are many significantly better ways to achieve this. Such as mailSettings as Rashedul.Rubel suggested.

Answer (score 2):

```
//you can try by using the following smtp configuration in web.config

<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="SMTPServer" port="" userName="username" password="password" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Email" value="you@yourwebsite.com"/>
  </appSettings>

//where host=your server name, port=server machines port number

//and in code behind write the code as follows:

       string fromEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"].ToString();
    string toEmail = txtEmail.Text;
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromEmailAddress, toEmailAddress);
    message.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
    message.Body = txtBody.Text;

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Send(message);
```

Comment: Thanks for the information but it is not a form, just a textbox from where to send the mail+attachment to(automaticly) and a button (send)

Answer (score 0):

```
Action Mailer can be used to send email. email can be sent with attachment without using form. 
web config configuration for the smtp:

  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="25" userName="username" password="password" defaultCredentials="false" enableSsl="true"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>

 configure smtp in IIS

attachment can be done using Attachments.Inline["" + fileName] = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

for more information see the link below:
http://ratiyaranmal.blogspot.com/2012/06/send-email-in-mvc-using-actionmailer.html
```